# How to update array value with same key in session storage

Tags: angularjs

I have two tabs in my admin interface. I am storing the response in my session storage. When I do the updation of any records in the tab or if I insert new record also, the same thing should be reflected in the storage also. But currently, the changes are not getting reflected in the storage. I tried my best to sort out, but I could not able to succeed. Any help/advice greatly appreciated.

Angularjs:

```
$scope.Pool = [];
if (!localStorageService.get('Pool')) {
   Role.getPool().success(function(data) {
    if (data.responseCode === 0) {
    _.forEach(data.response.demoPool, function(value, key) {
    dataObj = {};

    dataObj.id = value.poolId;
    dataObj.value = value.poolName;

    $scope.Pool.push(dataObj);
});

localStorageService.set('Pool', $scope.Pool);
} else {
   $scope.alerts.alert = true;
   $scope.alerts.type = 'danger';
   $scope.alerts.msg = data.errorMsg;                    
 }                 
})
```

Answer (score 2):

First time it will do because **!localStorageService.get('Pool')** becomes true. But next time it will return false because storage has value already, it will not get inside the if condition. so to resolve this remove the session storage **'Pool'**  to allow to execute your **Role.getPool().success(function(data) {**

Answer (score 1):

```
          if (!sessionStorage.length) {
          // Ask other tabs for session storage
          localStorage.setItem('getSessionStorage', Date.now());
        };

window.addEventListener('storage', function (event) {
            switch (event.key) {
              case 'getSessionStorage':
                // Some tab asked for the sessionStorage -> send it
                localStorage.setItem('sessionStorage', JSON.stringify(sessionStorage));
                localStorage.removeItem('sessionStorage');
                break;
              case 'sessionStorage':
                // sessionStorage is empty -> fill it
                var data = JSON.parse(event.newValue);
                for (key in data) {
                  sessionStorage.setItem(key, data[key]);
                }
                break;
            }
          });
```